# How save is Tor and there relays?

Tags: security

What if i run a relay and a person downloads illegal content? Example: Like child porn that goes past my relay? In general speaking i am just as bad as the person that downloads such content. So even in here, the Netherlands, i will be fined and will be in court because of it.

Reason i ask this is because i would like to run a guard relay, but my concern is i do not want to get to court because, like i stated above, a entity is using it to get illegal content. Is there anything known about this? Thank you in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a Guard or Middle relay is totally fine and won't cause you any trouble. This is because all the traffic you forward and receive as a Middle/Guard relay is end to end encrypted between the target server and the client (means as a relay you can't read the forwarded traffic).

This means even if someone would download something illegal using your relay, you couldn't be held responsible because it would be impossible to prove that the illegal content actually was relayed by your relay and not just the exit relay.

I, myself have been running a Guard/Middle relay for more than two years now and have never gotten any trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your findings and answers it gives me a bit more of ease to go take next step to put up a relay. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am running multiple relays for 1-2 years now. Guards and middlerelays, and never got any issues or problems because of this.
Exits are another theme but you dont need to worry because of running a guard or middlerelays.

Comment: If you want a little extra in security you can get a vps in a country with strict privacy laws or weak law enforcement. Iceland, Bulgaria, Belize, Hungary and a lot more are recommendet. But for guards and middles this is not a must, just a possible extra option.